# Is there element by element comparison for multi-dimensional arrays in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have two arrays of size (n, n) and I want to do an element by element comparison returning a boolean matrix of size (n, n).

Let's say,

```
Dim A(4, 4) as Integer = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 2, 3, 4, 1 }, { 3, 4, 1, 2 }, { 4, 1, 2, 3 } };
Dim B(4, 4) as Integer = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4 } };
```

I'm looking for something where if `C = (A == B)`

```
C = { { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
```

The closest thing I can seem to find is to compare row by row using `SequenceEqual()`, but that returns a single boolean per row, where I need a row of booleans.

This would be done very easily in Python using pandas or numpy. Is there a way to do this in .NET or do I need to implement nested for loops to do what I want?

Comment: I think you are asking about: [Enumerable.Intersect Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.8.1). No experience of this myself, but take a look.

Comment: Did you mean `C = { { True, True, True, True }, { False, False, False, False }, { False, False, False, False }, { False, False, False, False } };`, or do you actually want ones and zeros instead of boolean values? (Also, it's "Dim A(3, 3) As ..." to get a 4x4 array - the last index is specified instead of the number of elements.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for loops will do the job:

```
Dim P = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}}
Dim Q = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}

n = P.GetUpperBound(0)

Dim R(n, n) As Boolean

For i = 0 To n
    Dim eql = True
    For j = 0 To n
        If P(i, j) <> Q(i, j) Then
            eql = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    For j = 0 To n
        R(i, j) = eql
    Next
Next

' Show values...
For i = 0 To n
    Dim t(n) As Boolean
    For j = 0 To n
        t(j) = R(i, j)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine($"({String.Join(", ", t)})")
Next
```

Which outputs:

```
(True, True, True, True)
(False, False, False, False)
(False, False, False, False)
(False, False, False, False)
```

**However,** I wonder if the data would be better represented as an array of arrays (a.k.a. a [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/#jagged-arrays)), in which case:

```
Dim A = {({1, 2, 3, 4}), ({2, 3, 4, 1}), ({3, 4, 1, 2}), ({4, 1, 2, 3})}
Dim B = {({1, 2, 3, 4}), ({1, 2, 3, 4}), ({1, 2, 3, 4}), ({1, 2, 3, 4})}

Dim n = A.GetUpperBound(0)

Dim C(n)() As Boolean

For i = 0 To n
    C(i) = New Boolean(n) {}
    Array.Fill(C(i), A(i).SequenceEqual(B(i)))
Next

' Show values...
For Each x In C
    Console.WriteLine($"({String.Join(", ", x)})")
Next
```

Which shows the same output, although it is a jagged array.

(The [`Array.Fill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.fill) method was added in .NET Core 2, so if you are using .NET Framework you will need another small loop to set the values.)

Answer (score 0):

you can perform element-by-element comparisons for multi-dimensional arrays using nested loops.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim matrixA = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}}
    Dim matrixB = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}

    Dim n = matrixA.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim resultMatrix(n, n) As Boolean

    For i = 0 To n
        Dim areEqual = True
        For j = 0 To n
            If matrixA(i, j) <> matrixB(i, j) Then
              areEqual = False
            Exit For
            End If
        Next
        For j = 0 To n
           resultMatrix(i, j) = areEqual
        Next
    Next

    ' Show values...
    For i = 0 To n
        Dim row(n) As Boolean
        For j = 0 To n
          row(j) = resultMatrix(i, j)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine($"({String.Join(", ", row)})")
    Next
End Sub
```

Outputs:

```
(True, True, True, True)
(False, False, False, False)
(False, False, False, False)
(False, False, False, False)
```